# Нужны ли кавычки

Tags: пунктуация

На войне действует закон: сам погибай, а товарища выручай. Нужны ли выделить кавычками "сам погибай, а товарища выручай" и с какой буквы писать эту фразу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На войне действует закон: сам погибай, а товарища выручай.

Это предложение оформляется как обычное БСП со значением пояснения. Не думаю, что вторая часть является дословным цитированием или названием закона.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, Вы меня очень выручили и развеяли мои сомнения.